# Jumpy animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, smooth-scrolling

I'm using this code on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.title').click(function() {
    $('.info').slideUp(800);
    $('.title').removeClass('flip');
    $(this).parent('div').find('.info').slideDown(800);
  });

  $('li.active').closest('.info').slideDown(800);
});
```

The animation is very jumpy in any browser I tested on my computer. If I check it in js-fiddle the animation is quite smooth. What's happening?

Here's the [js-fiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/8XkBY/1/).

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the issue, it won't be easy to solve

Answer (score 0):

It runs smoothly for me in the fiddle link.  However are you sure what you have coded is what you want to happen?  The way your calls are stacked, things might appear to be happening out of order.

You might want to look into doing callbacks after each animation is finished i.e.:

$('.info').slideUp(800,function(){

```
//...do work in here (i.e. remove classes, proceed with other animations/slides);
```

});

Comment: thx jkat98 for your answer...in the meantime I have managed it by using this script: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.title').click(function() { $('.content').fadeOut(200); $('.info').slideUp(1000); $(this).parent('div').find('.content').fadeIn(1800);    
$(this).next('.info').slideDown(800, function() {var project = $(this).parent('.project');
$.smoothScroll({ scrollTarget: project, easing: 'swing', speed: 400, offset: -30 }); }); });
$('li.active').closest('.info').fadeIn(800);
$('li.active').closest('.info').find('.content').css('display','block').fadeIn(800);
});
`